# Unable to convert the date format "MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a"

Tags: java-8

I am trying to convert a String like this `Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:00 PM` to Java LocalDateTime. Please have a look at the below code snippet.

```
        String str1 = "Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:00 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a")
                .toFormatter();
        LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(str1, formatter1);
        System.out.println("Output: " + dateTime1);
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:00 PM' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:494)
    at com.techopact.kafkautil.Trail.main(Trail.java:36)
```

After spending an awful amount of time and going through numerous docs, below code is the closest working code I could get.

```
        String str2 = "May 13, 2021, 07:47:03";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss")
                .toFormatter();
        LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(str2, formatter2);
        System.out.println("Output: " + dateTime2);
```

Output:

```
Output: 2021-05-13T07:47:03
```

As you can see the above code works only for the month **May** and I had to remove **AM/PM** from the input String.
Can you please let me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, I had to add Locale.ENGLISH to the formatter. I wonder what difference it makes. Please let me know in the comments.

```
        String str1 = "Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:00 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(str1, formatter1);
        System.out.println("Output: " + dateTime1);
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in your first code, you just need to use **`'hh'`** instead of **`'HH'`** in the pattern and it will work fine as shown below.

> **Reason:** **`'hh'`**- It is used for 12 hour format **`'HH'`**- It is used for 24 hour format

*You can refer the date and time patterns as shown in table from the official doc as well* ([SimpleDateFormat official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

**Cases:**

1. If the input is in 12 hour format like `"Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:26 PM"`, the pattern should be like `"MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"`
2. If the input is in 24 hour format like `"Jul 13, 2021, 19:47:26"`, the pattern should be like `"MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss"`

**Code for Case1:**

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:26 PM";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a")
        .toFormatter();
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(str1, formatter1);
    System.out.println("Output: " + dateTime1);
  }
}

Output: 2021-07-13T19:47:26
```

**Code for Case 2:**

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "Jul 13, 2021, 19:47:26";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss")
        .toFormatter();
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse(str1, formatter1);
    System.out.println("Output: " + dateTime1);
  }
}

Output: 2021-07-13T19:47:26
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: hmmm, I wonder how it is working for you. I just copy pasted your code and I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jul 13, 2021, 07:47:26 PM' could not be parsed at index 0
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
```

Comment: @Andy, It is working fine for me.Which case you have tried first?

Comment: @Andy I have just checked again and it is working fine for me with both JDK 1.8 and JDK 17. May you please check it once again at your end.

Comment: I tried both the cases, but I am more interested in the case1.

Comment: I am using java version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19 LTS

Comment: I am not sure, if I am missing something really silly, so I added the screenshot of the program.

Comment: @Andy.. This is something weird , as per the screenshot everything looks absolutely fine. Can you try to compile and run the code in the terminal or command prompt.

Comment: I tired to run it from 2 different terminal. I got the same error.  :-|

Comment: @Andy Is it working now?